# Gauss-Markov-Theorem not holding true when error terms not normally distributed?

Tags: least-squares, blue, least-absolute-deviations, gauss-markov-theorem

I tried to simulate some stuff around the Gauss-Markov-Theorem when I stumbled over something I cannot explain. I tried to simulate the density of an OLS estimator and a LAD (least absolute deviations) estimator.
Here's my R code:

```
library(L1pack) # for LAD estimation
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, length.out = n)
n_runs <- 10000
beta <- cbind(numeric(n_runs), numeric(n_runs))
for(i in 1:n_runs){
  u <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 3) # normal distribution
  #u <- scale(rexp(n, rate = .2), scale = FALSE) # exponential distribution, mean centered
  #u <- rt(n, 2) # t-distribution
  y <- x + u
  
  R_OLS <- lm(y ~ x)
  beta[i, 1] <- R_OLS$coefficients[2]
  
  R_LAD <- lad(y ~ x)
  beta[i, 2] <- R_LAD$coefficients[2]
}

beta %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  rename("OLS" = X1, "LAD" = X2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = OLS:LAD) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, color = name))+
  geom_density()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(.5,1.5))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
The result is what I was expecting: The OLS estimator has a smaller variance and is therefore "better".

However, when I don't use normally distributed error terms when generating my data (see commented out lines in code), things don't turn out as I would have expected:
[image]

Now OLS doesn't perform better, which to me looks like a violation of the BLUE (best linear unbiased estimator) principle.

Whats going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAE regression gives biased regression parameters for symmetric error?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467783/mae-regression-gives-biased-regression-parameters-for-symmetric-error) In summary, minimizing absolute deviations is a nonlinear estimator, meaning that Gauss-Markov does not apply.